# Why is this property swallowing errors?

Tags: ember.js

I have a property that depends on another property. There is an error in my code that happens when the other property is present. The error is being swallowed by something, probably Ember. This makes debugging the error very hard. I have tried setting Ember.onerror to a function that just logs the error, it makes no difference.

Why is Ember swallowing this error, how can I make it not?

Code:

```
App.DashboardController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  leaderboard: function() {
    console.log("calling leaderboard");
    var ces = this.get("engagements");
    if (ces) {
      console.log("before");
      throw new Error("bad thing");
      console.log("after");
    }
    console.log("done")
  }.property("engagements")
})
```

Console log:

```
calling leaderboard
done
(setting engagements)
calling leaderboard
before
```

Version: Ember.js RC6, development

Comment: Hmm I don't receive this error, please give a look here http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/kXj77/.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the property "engagements" was being set inside a promise fulfilment handler. This article explains how to catch errors that occur in those: http://blog.sensible.io/2013/06/10/promise-ate-my-homework-exception.html